# Iterate through ArrayWritable - NoSuchMethodException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, iteration, nosuchmethoderror

I just started working with MapReduce, and I'm running into a weird bug that I haven't been able to answer through Google. I'm making a basic program using ArrayWritable, but when I run it, I get the following error during Reduce:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable.<init>()
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$ValuesIterator.readNextValue(Task.java:1276)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$ValuesIterator.next(Task.java:1214)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceValuesIterator.moveToNext(ReduceTask.java:250)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceValuesIterator.next(ReduceTask.java:246)
at PageRank$Reduce.reduce(Unknown Source)
at PageRank$Reduce.reduce(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:522)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
```

I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1. Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.join.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TempClass {

  public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
  implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, ArrayWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, ArrayWritable> output,
        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

      String[] arr_str = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        output.collect(new Text("my_key"), new ArrayWritable(arr_str));
    }
  }    

  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase
  implements Reducer<Text, ArrayWritable, Text, ArrayWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<ArrayWritable> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, ArrayWritable> output,
        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

      ArrayWritable tmp;

      while(values.hasNext()){
          tmp = values.next();
          output.collect(key, tmp);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, TempClass.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(ArrayWritable.class);
    job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths( job, new Path( args[0] ) );
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath( job, new Path( args[1] ) );

    job.setJobName( "TempClass" );

    JobClient.runJob(job);
  }
}
```

If I comment below lines (Reduce Class):

```
      //while(values.hasNext()){
      //    tmp = values.next();
          output.collect(key, tmp);
      //}
```

everything will be ok. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A Writable for arrays containing instances of a class. The elements of
>   this writable must all be instances of the same class. If this
>   writable will be the input for a Reducer, you will need to create a
>   subclass that sets the value to be of the proper type. For example:
>   public class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable { public
>   IntArrayWritable() { super(IntWritable.class); } }

Here is from the docs of [ArrayWritable](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.java). Generally, `Writable` should have an constructor with no parameter.

I just modified your code to:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class TempClass {

    public static class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
        public TextArrayWritable() {
            super(Text.class);
        }

        public TextArrayWritable(String[] strings) {
            super(Text.class);
            Text[] texts = new Text[strings.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
                texts[i] = new Text(strings[i]);
            }
            set(texts);
        }
    }

    public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, ArrayWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, ArrayWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            String[] arr_str = new String[] {
                    "a", "b", "c" };
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                output.collect(new Text("my_key"), new TextArrayWritable(
                        arr_str));
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, TextArrayWritable, Text, TextArrayWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<TextArrayWritable> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, TextArrayWritable> output,
                Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            TextArrayWritable tmp;

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                tmp = values.next();
                output.collect(key, tmp);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, TempClass.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(TextArrayWritable.class);
        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJobName("TempClass");

        JobClient.runJob(job);
    }
}
```