# Passing a Java List from Mapper to Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, collections, mapreduce

I am trying to write  Map Reduce code where mapper takes a file input with record values separated by comma, I am splitting the line based on comma and making a set of each line and finally adding each set to a list collection.

I am not sure how can I write it to the context and pass to the reducer, or more specifically what data type is used for a Java List collection in Map Reduce. I have heard about Array Writable but not able to implement it in my code.
Plz see the code below:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
{

    List<HashSet> listA=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HashSet>();
    Set<Set> finalset=new HashSet();
    Set<String> hs3;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException 
    {

        String line = value.toString();
        String[] str=line.split(",");
        HashSet<String> hs=new HashSet<>();
         for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
         {
             hs.add(str[i]);
         }
         listA.add(hs);


         context.write(key, listtobepassed); //listA in this case
    }

}
```

And the input format is as;

```
N3H1P7RBS4QM_71,N3H1P7RBS4QM_72,N3H1P7RBS4QM_73
N3H1P7RBS4QM_143,N3H1P7RBS4QM_144,N3H1P7RBS4QM_167046,N3H1P7RBS4QM_328681,N3H1P7RBS4QM_328682
N3H1P7RBS4QM_145,N3H1P7RBS4QM_167047,N3H1P7RBS4QM_328683
N3H1P7RBS4QM_193,N3H1P7RBS4QM_194,N3H1P7RBS4QM_167088,N3H1P7RBS4QM_167089
```

Updating the question: I am trying to run a transitive closure program through Map Reduce on the input;
example:
Input

```
Ref1, Ref2, Ref3
Ref3
Ref4, Ref5, Ref6
Ref7, Ref8, Ref9     
Ref9
Ref10, Ref11
Ref11, Ref12
```

Output Should be Like:

```
Ref1, Ref2, Ref3,Ref4,Ref5,Ref6
Ref7, Ref8, Ref9
Ref10, Ref11, Ref12
```

the common input values merge together.

My Java code looks like

`public class TestList {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    List<HashSet> ls=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HashSet>();

     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/inputfilepath"));
     String Data;

     while((Data=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
         String[] DataLine=Data.split(",");
         HashSet<String> hs =new HashSet();
         for(int i=0;i<DataLine.length;i++)
         {
             hs.add(DataLine[i]);

         }
         ls.add(hs);
     }
     br.close();
     //System.out.println(ls.iterator().next());
     Iterator<HashSet> itr=ls.iterator();
     HashSet<String> hs2=null;
     while(itr.hasNext())
     {
         HashSet<String> ele=itr.next();

         for (HashSet<String> hs1 : ls) 
         {
             if(!Collections.disjoint(hs1, ele))
             {
                hs2=new HashSet<String>(hs1);
                hs2.addAll(ele);
                ls.remove(ele);
                ls.remove(hs1);
             }

         }
         ls.add(hs2);

     }

     int counter=0;
     BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("transitiveoutput.txt"));
     for(Set s: ls)
     {
         bw.write(s.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "").trim());
         bw.newLine();
            System.out.println(s.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "").trim());
     }
     System.out.println("Transitive Closure comepleted.....");
     bw.close();

}
```

I am able to achieve the output in Java but for huge files its taking infinite time, so would like to replace it with a Map Reduce.

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: Check this for help on ArrayWritable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274668/iterate-through-arraywritable-nosuchmethodexception

Comment: I am not able to understand, how the first 3 lines get converted to "Ref1, Ref2, Ref3,Ref4,Ref5,Ref6". In your code, you are just splitting the line on comma (,) and putting the elements in the set and emitting. Not sure, what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Manjunath Yes, I am splitting them based on comma and adding each to a HashSet and Finally the HashSet to a List. Next I am cloning the List and comparing each element(set) of the list to remaining all and if there's is any intersection between two sets then putting them together. See my Java Code below:

public class Test
{

Comment: @ Manjunath I am updating the question with my java code! please see.

Comment: I got it. I was able to execute the standalone program. Let me see, if we can find a MapReduce solution for this. I will answer this, if I find a solution.

Comment: Sure Thing! Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: Implementing Transitive Closure using MapReduce is a complex problem. There are some papers on this. For e.g. https://asingleneuron.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/distributedalgorithmsfortransitiveclosure.pdf. I came across this solution using Pig: http://hortonworks.com/blog/transitive-closure-in-apache-pig/. If you replicate your logic in the stand alone program to MapReduce, it won't scale (your solution is still O(n^2)). You need to have a series of MapReduce jobs, which will do this in stages. I would love to implement it. I'll post a solution, if and when I implement it.

Comment: Great! I will read the papers and try to understand! Thanks Again.